# Will Kirchoff's voltage law work in a vacuum

Tags: basic, kirchhoffs-laws

Kirchoff's voltage rule tells us that the sum of voltages around a closed loop in a circuit will equal zero.
If a battery sits on a table, using KVL and treating air as matter with high resistance makes a KVL loop with a voltage gain of the battery's voltage which gets lost to the air.

If this battery floats in a near-perfect vacuum like space that has little matter and no interference will KVL still be applicable to create a "mesh"/loop around the battery?

Comment: You answered your own question. You said "closed loop **in a circuit**..." In a vacuum (at low voltage) there is no current flow so no circuit so KVL does not apply.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson so you're implying that when engineers make space telescopes like Hubble they don't use KVL because KVL is invalid in space?

Comment: @lmn32 Hubbles uses wires.

Comment: When engineers use KVL in space they first **create circuits**. The vacuum of space does not constitute a "circuit" in the normal conventional sense.

Comment: @lmn32 that comparison was ... strange, because all electrical loops in that satellite are just that: loops *inside* a device, which happens to fly through space. Just like the planet you're currently residing on.

Comment: Don't be silly. When Elliot says "in a vacuum" he is not saying that conductors don't conduct in a vacuum. He's saying that current won't flow through the vacuum of space. If there's a conductor there I don't think we could call the space it occupies a vacuum even if there is no gas in the conductor.

Comment: A vacuum (thermionic) tube works, not due to the vacuum, but due to the *lack of air to interfere with thermionic emission.*  To do vacuum-tube-like "conduction" in space, you'll still need a glowing filament, a hot cathode, an anode, and high voltages to accelerate electrons - essentially everything in the vacuum tube.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, As long as the conditions are there for the electrostatic potential to be well-defined, KVL formally applies. Vad = Vab + Vbc + Vcd, for any choice of 4 locations a, b, c, and d. This equation might not be useful for solving for the voltages, but will hold as long as the situation is (quasi)static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Kirchoff's voltage rule tells us that the sum of voltages around a closed loop in a circuit will equal zero.

Of course, that applies everywhere, even with a lack of conductors. That's a direct result of electrical potential being a potential field.

(this assumes we're in the DC case.)

A potential field is a field, i.e.

> an amplitude (here: voltage) defined on a space (e.g. a 2D plane or 3D space), where no matter *which* path you take, the integral over all amplitudes on the points you travel is always 0 when that path is closed.

The direct consequence is that, yes, even in absence of a current, the voltages add up to zero – just: that has little effect, since there's no charges that these voltages move.

KVL makes a simplification: with a lot of precision, we really only care about the currents that flow through conductors when there are conductors.

Comment: "this assumes we're in the DC case" // I agree. When there are time-varying magnetic fields, the work to be done when moving a charge from one point to another now depends on the path, and the work to be done when moving a charge in a closed loop could be non-zero.

Comment: @AlejandroNava well, that's exactly the reason why electromagnetic waves are able to actually transport power :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, KVL applies even in a vacuum. Take any path from a fixed point to other points and then back to the original point, and the total voltage change around the loop will be zero. It doesn't matter what path you take, or how much resistance is present along that path, or how much current may or may not be flowing. The voltage potential between two points is *path independent*, and the voltage potential between any point and itself is therefore 0, regardless of path.

KVL is directly entailed by of one of "Maxwell's"* equations (Faraday's Law of Induction), and the assumption that the area under investigation is not subject to a time-varying magnetic field.

Faraday's Law states:

$$\nabla \times E = -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$

If there is no time-varying magnetic field, this implies that

$$\nabla \times E = 0$$

which means that E is a conservative field. Being a conservative field implies that E is the gradient of a potential function, (which we call V)

$$E = \nabla V$$

V, being a potential function implies that the sum of changes around a loop must be 0 (which entails that KVL holds).

*The equations called "Maxwell's Equations" were first formulated in their modern form by the electrical engineer Oliver Heaviside.

Comment: This is only true if the **path** is conductive and forms a complete circuit.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson. No, it is true for _all_ paths, whether they are conductive or not.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, it's true so long as there are no changing magnetic fields passing through the region being studied. It does not depend on any conductive path being present.